# Sudden blank page on WordPress Admin Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My WordPress Admin Dashboard is experiencing an issue which I have never encountered before. I have not made any updates/changes on WordPress and any plugins. Yet, suddenly my WordPress Admin Dashboard has become like the attached image below. [image]

**What I have tried so far to fix this issue:**

(1) Increased the WP_MEMORY_LIMIT but it **did not worked** out

(2) Tried to change `wp-admin\includes\screen.php` on line 706:

```
from <?php echo self::$this->_help_sidebar; ?>
to <?php echo $this->_help_sidebar; ?>
```

But my screen.php file has less than 300 lines of code and does not contain `<?php echo self::$this->_help_sidebar; ?>` in it. So I cannot change it.

(3) Disabled all plugins(10) by renaming the "plugins" folder and it **did solved** the blank page issue.

(4) I have set WP_DEBUG to TRUE and got the following messages:

```
Undefined property: wpdb::$connect_errno in /local/www/html/xxxxx/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 684 Notice: Undefined property: wpdb::$connect_errno in /local/www/html/xxxxx/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 684 Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in WPAC_Nav_Menu_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in /local/www/html/xxxxx/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3764 Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in Genesis_Featured_Post_with_title is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use
__construct()
instead. in /local/www/html/xxxxx/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3764 Notice: Constant FORCE_SSL_ADMIN already defined in /local/www/html/xxxxx/wp-config.php
```

(5) Disabled the plugins(10) one by one to find out which plugin was the culprit. Interesting enough is that whichever plugin I disabled the blank page issues was **still solved** . This made it difficult for me to isolate which plugin was the culprit. I might be totally wrong thinking that the plugins may be causing this blank page issues. Currently, I have no idea how to solve/approach this issue and why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated very much!

Comment: Is your WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php set to true?

Comment: @Sheedo Yes, I have. Please see point (4) in my updated question.

Comment: Have you done anything to fix the error message that showed up?

Comment: Its not whitepage/dead, as you wouldnt even see anything.. Have a look at your error logs, perhaps something died in view buffering.

Comment: @Sheedo, it seems that there was an issue on the server side. I will update my solution soon on this question.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, thank you for your answer. But it was a server issue I was experiencing. I will post my solution soon.